# Delimit an area with Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, maps

Delimit an area with Google Maps for Android.

I was testing with the object LatLngBounds https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/LatLngBounds#LatLngBounds(com.google.android.m4b.maps.model.LatLng, com.google.android.m4b.maps.model.LatLng), but there are points belonging to an area and are discarded. So it is not very accurate.

I would like to know how to determine whether or not a point belongs to a specific area.

For example:
https://www.google.co.ve/maps/place/Parroquia+Olegario+Villalobos/@10.6772967,-71.6175539,14.75z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8e8998c4914c735b:0x6c02b649811c00b2?hl=es-419

Right now I'm thinking about making a query to the Google Web service to get the id of the place, and check each time (~1 minute) if the user is still within the área.

What is the best/simplest way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Google Web service I am trying to use https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=8.9891287,-79.518959